# Python-Creating List Of Grid Positions Within A Certain Bound Given A Distance

Tags: python, math

[two scenarios](https://i.stack.imgur.com/95TFm.png)

I have an x axis size, a y axis size, a render distance, a list of grid position numbers and a central grid position.

I am trying to create a list of all the grid positions within the render distance of a central grid position.

The size of the x and y axis may be different independently. Optimally this algorithm would not attempt to get positions where the render distance extends over the side of the x or y axis.

Thanks.

Comment: You may get downvoted as you're supposed to show what you've already tried. Something like this isn't particularly hard, I'd recommend figure out what you need to get `x+distance`, `x-distance`, `y+distance`, `y-distance` for a given `size`. It'll be very easy to add checks for the edge of the grid once you have these.

Comment: Oh I see, thanks. I'll give it a try, I'm guessing the easiest method is to give each square an x and y position and work it out using those as opposed to directly referring to the order number of specific squares?

Comment: Eh I'll write an answer since it'll be easier to read, I'll leave the maths for you to figure out though as it won't be too hard :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm writing this to help you answer your own question in the style that I would go about it. As with anything in coding, what you need to do is be able to break down a big problem into multiple smaller ones.

0. Design two functions to convert to and from (`x`, `y`) coordinates (optional, it'll make your life easier, but won't be as efficient, personally I would avoid this for a bit of a challenge).
1. Given `n`, `size` and `distance`, calculate `up`, `down`, `left` and `right`. If the size is different for different axis, then just provide the function with the correct one.

eg.

```
def right(n, size, distance):
    return n + size * distance

def down(n, size, distance):
    return n - distance
```

3. Given `size`, make sure the above functions don't go off the edge of the grid. Converting the points to `(x, y)` coordinates for this part may help.
4. Now you have the sides of the square, run the functions again to get the corners. For example, to get the top right corner, you could do `right(up(*args))` or `up(right(*args))`
5. With the corners, you can now calculate what's in your square. Converting the points to `(x, y)` coordinates will make it easier.

Comment: Thanks a lot, that's helpful. For some reason using x and y coordinates didn't cross my mind, probably because I'm doing this method to avoid inefficiently comparing large sums of values of coordinates so I wrongly instictively wanted to avoid them.

Comment: Like I said in the answer, I would prefer not using `x` and `y` given the choice, assuming I was able to figure out the calculations needed. The hard part would just be detecting if you've gone off the edge of the grid, but I don't think it'd be _that_ hard depending on your existing python knowledge :)